# LOOP through JSON data in stored procedure Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

MY fpo table looks like below

```
 id                             fo_data
  1          {"bene_first_name":{"value":"Chris1"},"bene_last_name":{"value":"Ronald"}}
  2          {"bene_first_name":{"value":"John"},"bene_last_name":{"value":"Wick"}}
  1          {"bene_first_name":{"value":"James"},"bene_last_name":{"value":"Cooper"}}
```

I have created a stored procedure as below and i am trying to push all the data of particular column "fo_data" into single JSON variable and I am trying to loop the obtained JSON data

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION file_compare()
RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' COST 100 VOLATILE AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  fpo_data jsonb;
  i JSONB;
BEGIN
  SELECT json_agg((fpdata))::jsonb
  FROM (SELECT fo_data AS fpdata
        FROM fpo LIMIT 100
    ) t  INTO fpo_data; 
  FOR i IN SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(fpo_data) LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'output from space %', i->>'bene_firstname';
  END LOOP;
  RETURN fpo_data;
END;
$BODY$;
```

I am getting the below output for `"RETURN fpo_data"`

```
 ["{\"bene_first_name\":{\"value\":\"Chris\"},\"bene_last_name\":{\"value\":\"Ronald\"}}",
  "{\"bene_first_name\":{\"value\":\"John\"},\"bene_last_name\":{\"value\":\"Wick\"}}",
   "{\"bene_first_name\":{\"value\":\"James\"},\"bene_last_name\":{\"value\":\"Cooper\"}}"
```

If i try to print `'bene_firstname'` like this

```
 RAISE NOTICE 'output from space %', i->>'bene_firstname'
```

I am getting the error as

```
 ERROR: operator does not exist: record ->> unknown.
```

If I print "i" alone I am getting the below data printed in console

```
NOTICE:  output from space ("""{\\""bene_first_name\\"":{\\""value\\"":\\""Chris90\\""},\\""bene_last_name\\"":{\\""value\\"":\\""Ronald\\""}}""")
NOTICE:  output from space ("""{\\""bene_first_name\\"":{\\""value\\"":\\""John\\""},\\""bene_last_name\\"":{\\""value\\"":\\""Wick\\""}}""")
NOTICE:  output from space ("""{\\""bene_first_name\\"":{\\""value\\"":\\""James\\""},\\""bene_last_name\\"":{\\""value\\"":\\""Cooper\\""}}""")
```

How to I get 'bene_firstname' from the above json array

Comment: That is surprising; it works for me. Are you sure that `i` is declared as `jsonb`, not as `record`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Sorry I declared "i" as record. I have changed it to jsonb. Now I am getting i->>'bene_firstname' but The is 'value' inside 'bene_firstname'. If I try to print  i->>'bene_firstname'->>'value' I am getting the error as 
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text ->> unknown

Comment: That would be `i->'bene_firstname'->>'value'`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am getting the ouptut as " output from space <NULL>" if I write i->'bene_firstname'->>'value'

Comment: Hard to say without knowing `fpo`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have added the structure and data of my table in my question above

Comment: Then this is to be expected, because the attribute is called `bene_first_name`, not `bene_firstname`. It seems that all your questions are only typos.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206703/discussion-between-sai-sri-and-laurenz-albe).

Comment: No, this question should be closed.

Comment: I think this is an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377). Why do you want to iterate over those elements to begin with? What is the actual, underlying problem you are trying to solve with that (very strange) approach? "Looping" over data is more often than not the wrong solution in a relational database

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION file_compare()
RETURNS TEXT LANGUAGE plpgsql COST 100 STABLE AS $BODY$
DECLARE
  fpo_data jsonb;
  i JSONB;
BEGIN
  SELECT json_agg(fo_data)::jsonb from (select fo_data from fpo limit 100) d into fpo_data;
  FOR i IN SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(fpo_data) LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'output from space %', i#>>'{bene_first_name,value}';
  END LOOP;
  RETURN fpo_data::text;
END;
$BODY$;
```

This assumes fo_data is a json field.  Notice I changed the function to STABLE as it doesn't change any data.

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: Yes. But how do I get 'value' in 'bene_firstname' i.e I am expecting the output as "Chris90" for first row

Comment: Ah-Sorry.  I corrected the code.  Somehow bene_firstname entered the conversation but it is bene_first_name according to the output in your code.  I changed to get value.  I also return text as the function is defined like that.

Comment: I have tried printing i->>'bene_first_name', but I am getting 'output from space <NULL>'

Comment: Did you try the code I posted?  i->>'bene_first_name' does not work as the bene_first_name field is a jsonb object.  i->'bene_first_name' should work and (i->'bene_first_name')::jsonb->>'value' too as it is a text field.  i#>>'{bene_first_name,value}' returns text too.

Comment: @BjarniRangnarsson I am still getting <NULL>. Also I cant go with your query as  my tables has thousands of records and your query is giving time out. So I need to write a subquery as I wrote

Comment: Ok.  I changed the procedure to limit rows correctly.  Try now.   The raise notice output is taking most of the time I suspect.  You would want to take out this limit in final version an without the raise notice.  But first try with the limit on.  The output should work  with this: i#>>'{bene_first_name,value}'

Comment: @BjarniRangnarsson I have tried your code. But still I am getting <NULL>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206711/discussion-between-bjarni-ragnarsson-and-sai-sri).